# Bulk Insert or Update Laravel Eloquent without Foreach Loop

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.1

Data structure is as follows:

> referral_statistics

```
id | registered_user_id | date | promoter_ref_revenue | writer_ref_revenue
```

Now for this Table I want to insert two arrays,
first one will is successfully getting inserted as follows:

```
$referralStats = ReferralStatistic::insert($userReferralStatsArray);
$referralStats = ReferralStatistic::insert($userWriterReferralStatsArray);
```

Now second array is **$userWriterReferralStatsArray**, while inserting this array I want to check if same **date** and same **registered_user_id** is repeated then it should update not insert the new row. How can I do it, or please suggest me if there is any other good way to implement it because there are large number of rows.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the `insert()` method you can use the  `updateOrCreate()` [Eloquent method](https://github.com/illuminate/database/blob/b2ed7f2f624742991948647a553a6961de86ef42/Eloquent/Builder.php#L262-277) or simply call the `save()` method of the model which updates the model if it exists

Comment: Hi how can I check if date and registered_user_id exists, if it does then it should update otherwise it should make new row